# Disabled button modified using for example firebug

Tags: html, security

Imagine that in a HTML file I have a disabled button. I might as well use Firebug to enable this button and so do the submission.

My question is: is there any way I disable this button and not allow this submission even when I modify the disabled property of the button in Firebug?

Should I always have to treat this problem on server side, thinking that this possibility could happen?

Comment: You can disable the submit with js or remove the button completely

Comment: Yes, you should always validate the submission server-side, because regardless of what you disable to the user and however you modify your form, a user can submit whatever he wants...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should **always** validate server-side . The client-side validation is just to facilitate correction by the customer and provide interactivity with him, thus preventing him submit all data and only then discover the correct format or a missing field and then be forced to repopulate all the fields.

The form may have been easily incorporated into another web site and then the action of the form directed to your website or the user inject some malicious code/data in the form. (See: [Wikipedia XSS](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) )

Any malicious user can easily bypass a disabled HTML button to activate it by making Firebug or worse, even if you could prevent it, he can simply create an HTML page and point to your destination URL in the form action, or even without creating a page, make an AJAX request. He may even develop a tool for this using PHP with cURL (or sockets ) library or any other programming language like . NET using a WebClient/WebRequest or Java with HttpURLConnection which in both cases are exactly what a browser would do to request a page or send data to another... (And this task can be done in 5 minutes by any Junior Developer)

You should never rely on the user and should never consider client-side validation as a part of security flow, since by being client-side, any information from there can easily be manipulated as has exemplified above.